# Non-stock kit item cannot be linked to Purchase Order

Tags: acumatica

In Sales Order, I'm trying to mark a non-stock kit item for PO. But I can't and I'm getting an error. Is there any particular reason why ? Cause I can raise the Purchase Order manually for it.

[image]

Edit:

It allows me to raise a PO for it. So is this a bug on the PO side ?

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add a non-stock kit to a PO.  The vendor wouldn't know which items to pick.  Think of a non-stock kit as a bundle.  It can include a mix of stock & non-stock items.  I recommend to create a pick ticket instead of a PO.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Ok, I get that. But it does allow raising a manual PO for it. I added the screen shot in my question.